# David Warner (Star Trek, Tron, The Omen, many more), RIP

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

David Warner passed away on July 24th, 2022 after losing his fight with cancer.  A prolific actor, Warner had many memorable roles both in and out of the sci-fi genres.

Trek fans will know Warner from roles such as Chancellor Gorkon in *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country* and the sadistic Cardassian interrogator Gul Madred in the two-part *TNG* episode “Chain of Command.”    Warner also had classic performances as the villainous Sark/Master Control Program/Ed Dillinger in *Tron*, Jack the Ripper in the 1979 sci-fi film *Time after Time*, “Evil” in *Time Bandits*, and as Lord Downey in the 2007 adaptation of Terry Pratchett’s *Hogfather*.

Warner’s work outside of the genre was no less memorable.  Perhaps best known to American audiences as Spicer Lovejoy in *Titanic*, Warner appeared in a wide range of films and television shows.   These ranged from light-hearted fare such as the 1983 Steve Martin comedy *The Man with Two Brains* to dark, edgy material such as *The Omen* and an uncredited (but sublime) appearance as the emotionally challenged Henry Niles in the Sam Peckinpah's harrowing film *Straw Dogs*.

Along with his on-screen work, Warner had a long career as a voice actor work.  Notable roles were as the Batman villain Ra’s al-Ghul and the maddened wizard Irenicus in the popular video game *Baldur’s Gate 2*.

[CNET Obituary](https://www.cnet.com/culture/entertainment/actor-david-warner-seen-in-star-trek-titanic-and-tron-dies-aged-80/)

[image: Warner]

[image: Warner as Gul Madred from ST:TNG]

[image: Warner as Jack the Ripper in Time after Time]

Comment: My first memory of him is in TMNT II: Secret of the Ooze.

Comment: He played St. John Talbot in Star Trek 5: The Final Frontier

Comment: They're going to illuminate his gravestone with four lights. Or five, depending on whom you ask. (One of the [best TNG episodes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chain_of_Command,_Part_II_(episode)), if you didn't catch the reference)

Comment: His [iconic voice performance as Irenicus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6LbhhoOSIw) is one of my favorite video game memories.

Comment: @A_S00 "I cannot be caged. I cannot be controlled. Understand this as you die, ever pathetic, ever fools!"

One of the best RPG villains of all time.  Warner was perfect for the role!

Comment: "End of line" - spoken with a quiet menace that really got to me as a young teen watching Tron for the first time. Awesome actor!

Answer (score 10):

To my mind, David Warner's voice was the most memorable aspect of his acting. He could always come across as believable, calm and serious; that's what made him so good in Star Trek VI, playing Gorkon, a Klingon who wasn't a violent psychopath. I saw his obituary [in the Guardian yesterday](https://www.theguardian.com/stage/2022/jul/25/david-warner-obituary) and felt certain I'd seen him in Babylon 5, but with only a picture to go by I had to consult wikipedia. With the voice it's a bit more obvious: Aldus Gajic, a man looking for the Holy Grail in space who is not a raving lunatic. Very few actors could have pulled this off.

[image: Aldus Gajic]

Of course, in universe, it's quite possible that Gajic was right. Given what we later discovered about the Vorlons, it's conceivable that they may have removed an item from Earth in the Middle Ages; maybe they put it there in the first place.